# How to add more than one fragment on presentation display?

Tags: java, android, fragment, presentation

My question comes from the use case that my android device is connected to 4K TV through HDMI. By default, it mirrors and upscales the content of my android device to 4K TV. The video quality is not ideal. I would like to use presentation mode to recreate the same content based on 4K resolution.

My app has multiple fragments. So naturally, I would like to find a way to re-use all of these fragments on presentation. I had done one fragment on presentation smoothly based on the following library. However, I am having difficulties to add the second fragment on presentation.

Based on the library cwac-presentation, I can create two fragments of webview on presentation, (for example, one webview for google.com, another for yahoo.com), but only the last one is shown. the previous one is  somehow hidden.

In theory, I could rewrite all my code using one fragment on presentation, that would be too much work.

Is there any limit on presentation? Or any suggestions to show two fragments on presentation?

https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-presentation

I had tried to show two PresentationFragments on local screen without problem. But when connected to 4K TV, only last fragment is shown.

I also tried to make the two fragment different and random sizes and positions, so they will not block each other. But it seems one fragment is also full screen size even though the view size is very small.

//Below shows the major part of changes based on cwac-presentation/demo/src/main/java/com/commonsware/cwac/preso/demo/MainActivity.java. If reversed the order of two ft.add()s, the last one will be shown.

```
@Override
  public void showPreso(Display display) {
    if (inline.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
      inline.setVisibility(View.GONE);
      inline2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
      prose.setText(R.string.secondary);

      Fragment f=getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.preso);
      Fragment f2=getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.preso2);

      FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            ft.remove(f);
            ft.remove(f2);
            ft.commit();
    }

    preso=buildPreso(display);

    preso2=buildPreso2(display);

    preso.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "preso");
    preso2.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "preso2");

    FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    ft.add(preso2, "preso2");
    ft.add(preso, "preso");
    ft.commit();

  }

  private PresentationFragment buildPreso(Display display) {
    return(SamplePresentationFragment.newInstance(this, display,
                                                  "http://www.google.com"));
  }
  private PresentationFragment buildPreso2(Display display) {
    return(SamplePresentationFragment.newInstance(this, display,
            "http://www.yahoo.com"));
  }
```

There are no error messages even though the second fragment is not shown. Ideally, two fragments will be shown together side by side.

Comment: Only one `Presentation` can be shown at a time. You need to set up a single `Presentation` that contains all of your content. As I mentioned [in your support question](https://community.commonsware.com/t/how-to-add-more-than-one-fragment-on-presentation-display/315/2), you could try to set up a single `PresentationFragment` that shows two regular child fragments as its content.

Comment: Thanks. nestedPresentationFragment is the solution.